# C++ Iterating Through Forward List Can't Access Element

Tags: c++, pointers, iteration, forward-list

I am using a forward iterator to process through a `forward_list` in C++.

```
for ( auto it = Edges.begin(); it != Edges.end(); ++it )
{
  if (findset(*it.start) != findset(*it.end))
    {
      edge_num += 1;
      total += *it.weight;
      tunion(*it.start, *it.end);
    }
  if (edge_num == numpoints - 1)
    {
      break;
    }
}
```

The `Edge` struct has `start`, `end`, `weight`, etc. associated with it. But I get the following error when compiling:

```
error: ‘struct std::_Fwd_list_iterator<Edge>’ has no member named ‘start’
if (findset(*it.start) != findset(*it.end))
```

Why doesn't the `*it` detect as being of type `Edge` and therefore have a `start` member?

Comment: Operator precedence. Look up *any* example of iterating over a container and calling methods of the container elements.

Comment: Just put parentheses around `(*it)`.

Comment: Or alternatively use the arrow operator: `it->start`

Answer (score 1):

`*it.start` is equivalent to `*(it.start)`. But you need `(*it).start`. You could add the parentheses, but the easiest and normal way to achieve this is to write `it->start`.